# execute code only after view controller was dismissed

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way to make sure resetScene() gets called only after the view controller vc has been dismissed? Any help would be appreciated.

```
vc.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
self.resetScene()
```

Answer (score 0):

> to make sure `resetScene()` gets called only after the view controller vc has been dismissed

Put the call to `resetScene()` inside the view controller `vc`'s `viewDidDisappear`.

Or put it inside `self`'s `viewDidAppear` and check first to make sure that the reason why we are reappearing is that `vc` was dismissed.

Comment: How do i add resetScene() to vc's viewDidDisappear? Do I have to create a custom view controller? @matt